# How can I extract the normals, textures, vertices, indices from blender .obj file to .h file?

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender

I have blender tool to create the 3D objects for OpenGL ES for android. I have tried the example in blender and exported the .obj file and .mtl file. I have used the `obj2opengl.pl` code file to extract the .h file from .obj file.

But after extraction, I got the normal points, vertex cords and indices. The texture coords are not extracted by `obj2opengl.pl` file. How can I generate the .obj file with textures using blender and how can i extract it?

Please, let me know proper tutorials for blender to openGL ES export. I need to generate the texture images also. this process is fully based on Augmented reality for android and I'm using QCAR SDK for augmented reality.